# Calling java methods in C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native

I need to call java methods from a c++ application. I've followed the instructions in these tutorials: http://hildstrom.com/projects/jni/index.html http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI. here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../Header/jni.h"

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM **jvm)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path= C:\\Users\\vhsn\\workspace-SP\\helloWorld\\src\\helloWorld";
    args.options = &options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
    int rv;
    rv = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &args);
    if (rv < 0 || !env)
        printf("Unable to Launch JVM %d\n",rv);
    else
        printf("Launched JVM! :)\n");
    return env;
}

void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env)
{
    jclass hello_world_class;
    jmethodID main_method;
    jmethodID square_method;
    jmethodID power_method;
    jint number=20;
    jint exponent=3;
    hello_world_class = env->FindClass("HelloWorld");
    main_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(hello_world_class, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    square_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(hello_world_class, "square", "(I)I");
    power_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(hello_world_class, "power", "(II)I");
    printf("carregou metodos");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(hello_world_class, main_method, NULL);
    printf("%d squared is %d\n", number,
        env->CallStaticIntMethod(hello_world_class, square_method, number));
    printf("%d raised to the %d power is %d\n", number, exponent,
        env->CallStaticIntMethod(hello_world_class, power_method, number, exponent));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    env = create_vm(&jvm);
    if(env == NULL)
        return 1;
    invoke_class(env);
    return 0;
}
```

Im compilling it with minGW, linking with jvm.lib located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib".

It compiles successfuly, but when I execute it only prints "Launched JVM! :)" and then crashes.
 When I try to debug, it crashes in the first GetStaticMethodID call. Im thinking it is not loading the HelloWorld.class properly but I have no clue why.

Does anyone ever faced a similar problem or have an idea what the problem might be?

I am on a windows machine 64bits, I am using java 32 bits because it didnt compile with jvm.lib from java 64 bits.

EDIT:

I have added a

```
if(env->ExceptionOccurred()){
            env->ExceptionDescribe();
        }
```

and it throws a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I think im not clearly understanding what to put in

```
options.optionString =  "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\vhsn\\workspace\\AAPlugin\\Debug";
```

Is it the path for the .class file or the .jar file?

Thank You Very Much!

Comment: Would be good if you also posted the code for your `HelloWorld` java class.

Comment: I think there's not enough information here to answer your question.  Could be the way you specified the path to `HelloWorld` in the `FindClass`, but we don't know the package that it is in.  Could be that it does not locate the class file, could be that the Java class does not have the method that you specified...  You should in any case be checking for exceptions after essentially all calls to JNI (especially if you know that you are crashing). An exception thrown at `FindClass` will not crash you until you make the *next* JNI call without first having cleared the exception on the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the class `HelloWorld` wasn't found, the `hello_world_class = env->FindClass("HelloWorld")` call returned null, so hello_world_class` is null, so the next call using it crashes.

You need to check the result of every JNI call, without exception.  You can assume exactly nothing with JNI.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I am now doing the check on wheter the hello_world_class and  throwing an exception using: if(env->ExceptionOccurred()){
   env->ExceptionDescribe();
  }  It is throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. But I have HelloWorld.class and HelloWorld.jar at the same location of my .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i got it.

I had to do two changes:

first i set the path to the .jar file including its name:

```
char * classPath = (char *) "-Djava.class.path=HelloWorld.jar";
```

Second in the findClass method,I had to specify its package name:

```
hello_world_class = env->FindClass("helloWorld/HelloWorld");
```

Thank you very much for the answers.